# Notepad User defined Language Folding LESS

Tags: less, notepad++

I have an Issue with Notpad++ and LESS. I can't get the normal folding to work.
Notepad++ is the Editor I prefer the most so I wouldn't want to change.
At the Moment a LESS file looks like:

[image: LESS in Notepad++]

I've searched and googled to find an solution but was unsuccessful.
Most of the time it says to go in the menu 'Define your language...' and define there the starting and endpoints.
I've tried that but the result doesn't change.

[image: Open Menu]

I would love some advice on how to fix this since the next project is the 5th or so with LESS and I'm getting pretty annoyed by files with 1500 lines without folding.

Thank you Guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So I've finally found an solution.
You not only need to ad '{' as start and '}' as endpoint, you also need to erase '{}' from Operators & Delimiters (4. tab).